# Not receiving notification from mirror api subscriptions

Tags: php, google-mirror-api, google-api-php-client

I downloaded the PHP quickstart from google ([link](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php)) and put it online on a secure site.

When subscribing to timeline events, the file `notify.php` should be called. However, this never happens. For example when removing a timeline card I expect notify.php to be called, but it is not.

I really don't know how to dive deeper into this. Any idea someone?

-- edit --

Some more info on the issue (it was a long day yesterday..) ;)

The subscription is being set, when printing the subscription I see that the redirect url is correct:

```
$subscriptions = $mirror_service->subscriptions->listSubscriptions();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($subscriptions);
echo '</pre>';
```

results in:

```
Google_SubscriptionsListResponse Object
(
    [__itemsType:protected] => Google_Subscription
    [__itemsDataType:protected] => array
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google_Subscription Object
                (
                    [callbackUrl] => https://url/to/notify.php
                    [collection] => timeline
                    [id] => timeline
                    [kind] => mirror#subscription
                    [__notificationType:protected] => Google_Notification
                    [__notificationDataType:protected] => 
                    [notification] => 
                    [operation] => 
                    [updated] => 2014-03-21T09:34:45.391Z
                    [userToken] => 108736261363015154260
                    [verifyToken] => 
                )

        )

    [kind] => mirror#subscriptionsList
)
```

In order to check if `notify.php` is called I'm creating a "log file" in a writable folder on the server:

```
<?php
// all the way on top of notify.php
$file = __DIR__ .'/db/log.txt';

function logfile($txt) {
    global $file;
    $str = is_file($file)? file_get_contents($file) : '';
    file_put_contents($file, $str ."\n". $txt);
}

logfile('--- notify.php is being run ---');

//..
```

The logfile is written when I request `https://url/to/notify.php`, but the file is not written when I expect the subscription callback to fire.

Also the url `https://url/to/notify.php` has been added to the redirect URIs in the Google Developer Console, along with the oauth2callback.php

Comment: Is the certificate for the https server self-signed?

Comment: Nope, it's a "real", signed by GeoTrust Inc.
However it is a "blue" certificate, not a "green" one. See: http://imgur.com/OVYTFLD

Comment: UPDATE: I found out that the google-api-php-client classes were outdated, so I updated the quickstart project with the new classes.
Unfortunately, the problem persists.
See my fork of the quickstart project: https://github.com/publicJorn/mirror-quickstart-php

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it fixed.. Or actually, nothing was wrong..

I assumed that I would get notifications of newly created and deleted timeline items. Believe I read this somewhere.
However, today a collegue walked in who actually owns a glass device (the only one in the company). When I started playing with the menu items (you can't use them in the quickstart webapp) I could reply to a card and: notify.php was actually called!

Too bad this isn't well documented in the quickstart app itself.. But I am happy now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check to make sure that the subscription is actually created and contains the callback URL that you expect it to be.

Take a look at `mirror-client.php:subscribe_to_notifications()` and the "insertSubscriptions" case in `index.php` to verify the URL of the subscription.

You may also wish to add this function (from https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/list) which will list your subscriptions. You can then use this to determine what URL is stored and verify that URL is a secure working one.

```
function printSubscriptions($service) {
  try {
    $subscriptions = $service->subscriptions->listSubscriptions();

    foreach ($subscriptions->getItems() as $subscription) {
      print 'Collection: ' . $subscription->getCollection();
      print 'User token: ' . $subscription->getUserToken();
      print 'Verify token: ' . $subscription->getVerifyToken();
      print 'Callback URL: ' . $subscription->getCallbackUrl();

      if ($subscription->getOperation()) {
        print 'Operation:';
        foreach ($subscription->getOperation() as $operation) {
          print '  * ' . $operation;
        }
        print 'Operation: ALL';
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was a bit vague in my explanation, sorry. The subscription is being set, see the updated question. Do you have another idea?